# Returning data where dates are at least 7 days apart

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, sql-server-2017

I'm interested in retaining only individuals in a Microsoft SQL Server query that have a value over a certain threshold on two separate dates. If the individuals have a score higher than 150 twice and the second date is at least 7 days after the first date, I would like to return their ID, the second date that their score was above 150, and the score on the second date.

Here is the data:

```
SubjectID   DATE         Score
001         01/11/2014   147
001         02/11/2013   151
002         02/10/2015   152
003         08/12/2013   155
002         01/31/2012   159
003         07/19/2016   157
```

So I for the results, I would like to return the following:

```
SubjectID   DATE         Score
002         02/10/2015   152
003         07/19/2016   157
```

As per a previous question I asked, I am using the following code to return the second date:

```
 SELECT *
    FROM Clinic a
    WHERE a.score > 150 
          AND a.date IN (SELECT MAX(b.date) 
                         FROM Clinic b 
                         WHERE b.subjectId = a.subjectId 
                                AND b.score > 150)
```

I think I would need to add something like the following to the WHERE statement:

```
AND (b.date - a.date) > 7;
```

Comment: what version of sql server? 2008, 2012, 2016? 2012 onward allows `lag`

Answer (score 2):

Just use `lag()`:

```
select c.*
from (select c.*, lag(date) over (partition by c.subjectid order by c.date) as prev_date
      from clinic c
      where c.score > 150
     ) c
where date > dateadd(day, 7, prev_date);
```

You can also approach this with a correlated subquery:

```
select c.*
from clinic c
where c.score > 150 and
      c.date > (select dateadd(day, 7, c2.date)
                from clinic c2
                where c2.subjectid = c.subjectid and c2.score > 150
               );
```

Comment: I received the following error when I ran your code:

Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: I think there are duplicates dates that I would need to account for. For example, if 01/01/2018 is the second date and is listed multiple times, there is an error. How do we only return one date if the date is listed multiple times?

Comment: @statsguyz . . . How do you choose among multiple rows on the same day?  Is there a timestamp for the latest?

Comment: There was prior to creating the temporary table. Now I just have multiple rows with the same subject ID and date (there is no longer any timestamp). I think I can just remove the duplicate rows prior to running any of these solutions.

Answer (score 2):

`LAG` is the way to go. But just in case you want to complete your original query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Clinic AS curr
WHERE Score > 150 
AND Date >= (
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 7, MAX(Date)) -- maximum date + 7 days
    FROM Clinic AS prev
    WHERE SubjectID = curr.SubjectID
    AND Date < curr.Date -- prev dates
    AND Score > 150
)
```

[DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=048b3e0cf2f575f22c74393ba522e765)

Comment: Should curr.SubjectID be prev.SubjectID and curr.Date be prev.Date? I'm getting an error for both, but when I change curr to prev for both the errors disappear.

Comment: @statsguyz I revised the query a bit and added test fiddle.

Comment: Your code is returning replicates if the date is the same day. For example, if the date is listed twice, it will return two rows each with the same date. How can I remove the replicate rows?

Comment: The result is technically correct. From the top of my head, try adding `AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Clinic AS same WHERE SubjectID = curr.SubjectID AND Date = curr.Date AND ID > curr.ID)` and it will return the row with highest id if there is a tie @statsguyz

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I added the DISTINCT keyword which resolves the issue.